# jquery carousel that reloads/refreshes page for each slide?

Tags: jquery, refresh, slideshow, carousel, jcarousel

I am interested in achieving a slideshow like this one: http://camillestyles.com/summer/10-best-splendid-summer-favors/

I want each slide to have it's own URL/page, and for the page to refresh with each slide.

Can someone tell me how this is achieved? Thank you so much, I've searched and searched, and just can't figure out how to achieve the page reload per slide with the jquery carousels/sliders out there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're thinking too much about jQuery and carousel projects when you can just accomplish it with static html.  Why not just make separate html pages and link to them?  Could be as simple as...

```
<a href="slide2.html">Next Slide</a>
```

With each slide in a separate html file (or however you have your server side set up).  If you do want a page refresh each time, this is probably the way to do it.

OR if you really want/need to change the full page with javascript, you can do that with...

```
window.location.href = "slide2.html";
```

OR if for some reason you still want the same html page (or server side view) to handle every slide, but you want the page to completely reload when you change slides, you could accomplish that by using a query string, something like this:

```
if (getParameterByName("slide") == 3) {
    $("#slide3").show();
}
else if (getParameterByName("slide") == 2) {
    $("#slide2").show();
}
else {
    $("#slide1").show();
}
```

If you're getting the query string like this, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/257494.

Then you would navigate like this:

```
<a href="slideshow.html?slide=2">Next Slide</a>
```